# Alternative to Backspace Parameter

Tags: solspace-tag, parameters

I asked [this question](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/13841/) some time back and it worked, however I don't see the backspace parameter listed in the docs now, nor do I see in the change log that it was removed. I tried it anyway and it doesn't work. Is there another way to remove the last comma from a list of tags? Thanks

Comment: What version of Tag and EE are you using? Can you show your template code for completeness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backspace=""` also takes newlines and extra spaces into account. So if you have

```
{exp:tag:tags backspace="2"}
   {tag_name}, 


{/exp:tag:tags}
```

...this will remove the last two linebreaks, leaving the last comma intact. Instead try removing these non-printing characters:

```
{exp:tag:tags backspace="2"}{tag_name}, {/exp:tag:tags}
```

This can happen not only with Tag, but with other add-on and native EE tags as well.

Comment: Got it working using backspace and incrementally increasing the value until the comma disappeared. Thanks.